# Child animator doesn't play animations

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, playback, animator

We have parent and child object (both non-static), each with it's own animator (both root motion). Parent animator moves the group in world space, child animator have to change visuals under the child object in depandance on the group world's position. Sometimes when play, every single animation shows ok. Sometimes when play but nothing in project was changed, the child object animations does not play. Can someone help to find sollution?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Hi, thank you, i don't know how to describe it better. In unity 3d Engine 2018.3.12, we have main object with animator as parent, under this object is child object with different, second animator. When Play the scene, sometimes (each secont/third try) the animator used on child object shows the animation is played, but the effect of the animation is not visible in the scene during the play mode and the inspector parametest of child object were not changed as exected - as was keyframes in the animation. No other script was used exept the unity animator